# How to wrap every third unique child element in new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to rebuild a section of a website where I don't have access to the DOM. Initially the section was built with tables and now I'm trying to rebuild the structure in divs. I've gotten as far as having one parent container with all contents of the table as children, like so:

[Chrome console window showing current progress of table reconstruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iivwn.png) 
I would like to, if possible, wrap the first corresponding "model-image-cell" element with the next corresponding first "model-info-cell" and so on.

With my limited knowledge, I've looped over the children and tried wrapping every three divs in a new container, however this just groups the model-images and model-info alike.

Could anyone please shed some light on this situation? Thanks.

Edit: apologies, thought previous code to how I got here would be pointless, but here is.

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  $('#ProductDataList').replaceWith(function(){
     $productListContainer = $("<div>", {html: $(this).html()});
     $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attribute){
          $productListContainer.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    });
    return $productListContainer;
  })


  $('#ProductDataList tbody').contents().unwrap();
  $('#ProductDataList tr').contents().unwrap();
  $('#ProductDataList td').replaceWith(function(){
     $div = $("<div>", {html: $(this).html()});
     $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attribute){
          $div.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    });
    return $div;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ProductDataList" class="product-data-list-table">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td data-imageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997.jpg" data-hoverimageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997-1.jpg" id="ModelImageCell1" class="model-image-cell">
    <span>Image</span>
</td><td data-imageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997.jpg" data-hoverimageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997-1.jpg" id="ModelImageCell1" class="model-image-cell">
    <span>Image</span>
</td><td data-imageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997.jpg" data-hoverimageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997-1.jpg" id="ModelImageCell1" class="model-image-cell">
    <span>Image</span>
</td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td class="model-info-cell"><div id="ModelLinkCell1" class="second-color model-link-container">
    <span>Image details/info</span>
    </div></td>
    <td class="model-info-cell"><div id="ModelLinkCell1" class="second-color model-link-container">
    <span>Image details/info</span>
    </div></td>
    <td class="model-info-cell"><div id="ModelLinkCell1" class="second-color model-link-container">
    <span>Image details/info</span>
    </div></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td data-imageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997.jpg" data-hoverimageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997-1.jpg" id="ModelImageCell1" class="model-image-cell">
    <span>Image</span>
</td><td data-imageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997.jpg" data-hoverimageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997-1.jpg" id="ModelImageCell1" class="model-image-cell">
    <span>Image</span>
</td><td data-imageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997.jpg" data-hoverimageurl="/Images/Models/150/7997-1.jpg" id="ModelImageCell1" class="model-image-cell">
    <span>Image</span>
</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="model-info-cell"><div id="ModelLinkCell1" class="second-color model-link-container">
    <span>Image details/info</span>
    </div></td>
    <td class="model-info-cell"><div id="ModelLinkCell1" class="second-color model-link-container">
    <span>Image details/info</span>
    </div></td>
    <td class="model-info-cell"><div id="ModelLinkCell1" class="second-color model-link-container">
    <span>Image details/info</span>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<button type="button" id="button">Rebuild</button>
```

This in turn created the structure detailed in the image above.

Edit: This is the expected result.

[image]

Comment: show me what you coode :D

Comment: @MaximeGirou Updated the OP. The previous code in my mind doesn't necessarily help the current issue. I'm just struck on where to go from here, mate.

Comment: can you put a sample table to unwrap so we can see the code in action. It would be easy to put every third model-info-cell into the previous corresponding model-image-cell but I feel like directly tackling the unwrapping function would be a lot better approach than just hacking through the elements

Comment: Hi, @AbanaClara just updated the OP with my approach, hopefully you understand how I'm going about it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding the code you’re working with, could you also show the html of the result you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/BananaAcid/jfah7p5c/) to solve your specific problem.

Relating to "With my limited knowledge, I've looped over the children and tried wrapping every three divs in a new container, however this just groups the model-images and model-info alike."

I think that point is interesting, so I tried something similar and thought this sub-case might be interesting.

```js
$(function() {
 var $inners = $('.container .inner');
  
  for (var i = 0; i<= $inners.length; i+=3) {
    var $els = [
      $inners.get(i),
      $inners.get(i+1),
      $inners.get(i+2)
    ];
  
    $($els).wrapAll('<div data-wrap="threes" />');
  }
  
});
```

```css
[data-wrap="threes"] {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Something</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  <div class="inner">Hello2</div>
  <div class="inner">Something2</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye2</div>
  <div class="inner">Hello3</div>
  <div class="inner">Something3</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye3</div>
  <div class="inner">Hello4</div>
  <div class="inner">Something4</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first reply you had was something I already tried, however your new solution is definitely along the right lines of what I'm after, man. Thank you. I'll toy about with the code and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Follow up. Got everything working the way I wanted. Thank you so much man.